# C Program to calculate sum of numbers X to Y using recursion

Tags: c

I have below code which works fine.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int calculateSum(int);

int main() {
    int num;
    int result;

    printf("Input number = ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    result = calculateSum(num);
    printf("\nResult from 1 to %d = %d", num, result);

    return (0);
}

int calculateSum(int num) {
    int res;
    if (num == 1) {
        return (1);
    }
    else {
        res = num + calculateSum(num - 1);
    }
    return (res);
}
```

Input number = 5
Result from 1 to 5 = 15

Now I am trying to give the program 2 inputs, from and to numbers.

Example: first input = 5, second = 8 and result should be = 26 (5 + 6 + 7 + 8)

Any ideas of how to go about this? failing thus far.

Comment: Looks like C. Why is this taggged C++, too? And `return` is not a function. Don't use parenthesis around its expression.

Comment: Free clue: this is a trick question. Stop thinking about code. Think logically. Try to think about what this question means. Keep thinking until a light bulb pops over the top of your head, and you slap yourself on the forehead.. The answer to this question is exactly one more line of code that you have written already. Free clue #2: the recursive function will still have exactly one parameter.

Comment: `from*(to-from+1)+calculateSum(to-from)` or `calculateSum(to)-calculateSum(from-1)`

Comment: Another clue: what's the difference between what you have and what you want?...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int calculateSum(int fromNum, int toNum) {
    int res;
    if (fromNum == toNum) {
        return (fromNum);
    }
    else {
        res = fromNum + calculateSum((fromNum + 1), toNum);
    }
    return (res);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, you are hard-coding `1` as the terminating point of the recursion.

What you need is to be able to use a *different* value for that, and the following pseudo-code shows how to do it:

```
def calculateSum(number, limit):
    if number <= limit:
        return limit
    return number + calculateSum(number - 1, limit)
```

For efficiency, if you break the rules and provide a limit higher than the starting number, you just get back the number. You *could* catch that and return zero but I'll leave that as an exercise if you're interested.

It should be relatively easy for you to turn that into real code, using your own `calculateSum` as a baseline.

---

I should mention that this is a spectacularly bad use case for recursion. In general, recursion should be used when the solution search space reduces quickly (such as a binary search halving it with each recursive level). Unless your environment does tail call optimisation, you're likely to run out of stack space fairly quickly.

Comment: @Sam, which is why the text contains the word "pseudo-code". Unlike others, I'd prefer to *teach* learners rather than just give them a canned solution. `${DEITY}` knows we have *enough* cowboys in the industry already :-)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of stopping when you reach `1`, stop when you reach `from`.

```
int calculateSum(from, to) {
    if (to == from) {
        return from;
    } else {
        return to + calculateSum(from, to-1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change 1 to from:

```
int calculateSum(int from,int to) {
    int res;
    if (to== from) {
        return (from);
    }
    else {
        res = to+ calculateSum(from,to - 1);
    }
    return (res);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use ternary operator.

```c
int calculateSum(int from, int to) {
    return from == to ? from : from + calculateSum(from + 1, to);
}
```